# OpenERP V7 graph showing always a line in 0

Tags: openerp-7

I'm trying to show a graph in openERP with two fields:

this is the View.XML :

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="id_view_contact">
            <field name="name">test.base.graph.view1</field>
            <field name="model">test.base</field>
            <field name="type">graph</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <graph string="contacts" type="bar" >
                    <field name="code"/>
                    <field name="value" operator="*"/>
                </graph>
            </field>
        </record>
```

and this is the python file of the module:

```
'code':fields.char("Code",size=64, required=True),
'value':fields.char("Name",size=128, required=True),
```

but when showing the graph, openerp get just the **code**, and show 0 for all the **value**

this is what showing openerp:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I correct this problem by changing the type of the fields from char to integer

```
'code':fields.integer("Code",size=64, required=True),
'value':fields.integer("Name",size=128, required=True),
```

I hope that help some one.